# File renaming by changing the order of the words within a filename

Tags: r, regex, file-rename

I have a folder with several files named as :

```
Point000_Channel2-BFP-Seq0000.nd2
Point000_Channel3-GFP-LP-Seq0001.nd2
```

I would like to rename the files and put the SeqXXXX in first place:

```
Seq0000_Point000_Channel2-BFP.nd2
```

Can anyone help with a piece of easy code?

Answer (score 0):

Using *regex*, extract "SeqXXXX", remove "SeqXXXX", then paste them together:

```
x <- c("Point000_Channel2-BFP-Seq0000.nd2",
       "Point000_Channel3-GFP-LP-Seq0001.nd2")

xNew <- paste(regmatches(x, regexpr("Seq[0-9]+", x)),
              gsub("-Seq[0-9]+", "", x), sep = "_")
xNew
# [1] "Seq0000_Point000_Channel2-BFP.nd2"   
# [2] "Seq0001_Point000_Channel3-GFP-LP.nd2"

# rename (not tested)
# file.rename(x, xNew)
```